# Differences between these two PIMPL approaches

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

So when trying to get in touch with the `PIMPL` idiom one finds two common ways of doing it:

1. Using *forward declaration* outside a class:

   ```
   class PimplClass;
   class VisibleClass
   {
   private:
       PimplClass* d_ptr;
   };
   ```
2. Using *forward declaration* inside a class:

   ```
   // *.hpp
   class VisibleClass
   {
   private:
      struct PimplClass;
      PimplClass* d_ptr;       
   };
   // *.cpp file:
   struct VisibleClass::PimplClass
   {
     int x;
   };
   ```

Two questions here:

- To be honest I have no idea why the second one works. I mean the expression *struct PimplClass* I only do know from forward declaration but not within a class. Can someone please explain this to me?
- Which solution to use? Where are the advantages or is it jsut a matter of taste?

Comment: Option 2 is just another forward declaration. Instead of a top-level class, you’re declaring a nested struct. But the logic is the same.

Comment: Formally, C++ doesn't have "forward declaration". There is just 'declaration".  `struct PimplClass;` is a declaration and it declares that `PimplClass` is the name of a class (within the scope of `VisibleClass`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do a forward declaration within class scope. So the second example is absolutely correct.

The main plus of second example is that your `PimplClass` can't be accessed from anywhere but from `VisibleClass` because it is declared (forward-declared) inside it's *private* section.

Answer (score 3):

- It's a forward-declaration too, but `PimplClass` is scoped inside `VisibleClass`.
- That second solution has the advantage of not dumping an internal type into the global namespace. Keeping `PimplClass` scoped inside `VisibleClass` makes complete sense.

In both cases, the Pimpl idiom should generally use a `std::unique_ptr` to tie the lifetimes of the interface and the Impl together, rather than a raw owning pointer.